# Reference a .net framework 4.5 service from .net core 2.1

Tags: .net

We have an asp.net core 2.1 mvc app in our solution that needs to reference services in other projects (same solution) targeting .net framework 4.5.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Can you switch your projects in the same solution to .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later?

Comment: We have around 60 or so projects in the solution.  It wouldnt be a small task to switch and then test.  Why? Is that required?

Comment: As far as I understand from this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard, .NET Core 2.0+ targets .NET Standard 2.0, so you will not be able to reference projects targeting below .NET 4.6.1. Hopefully, someone will correct me if I am wrong. I agree that it would be difficult to test this, but just in case you decide to switch you can use Target Framework plugin for Visual Studio to switch easily or just replace relevant tag in all .csproj files and then reload solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. .NET Core and .NET Full Framework cannot reference each other.

You could make a library .NET Standard, that one could be referenced from both if you want to share some simple things like data structures.

If one of your "services" communicates over something that is not a hard assembly reference, but maybe WebApi, then obviously the other project could call it just as any other external program, regardless of language or framework.